# Output the line numbers where a string appears

Tags: file, perl, text

I am trying to determine how many time a string, `Apples` appears in a text file and in which lines it appears.

The script outputs incorrect line numbers, instead it outputs numbers consecutively (1,2,..) and not the correct lines for the word.

#### file.txt

```
    Apples
    Grapes
    Oranges
    Apples
```

#### Goal Output

```
Apples appear 2 times in this file
Apples appear on these lines: 1, 4,
```

Instead my output as illustrated from the code below is:

```
Apples appear 2 times in this file
Apples appear on these lines: 1, 2,
```

#### Perl

```perl
my $filename = "<file.txt";

open( TEXT, $filename );

$initialLine = 10;    ## holds the number of the line
$line        = 0;
$counter     = 0;

# holder for line numbers
@lineAry = ();

while ( $line = <TEXT> ) {

    chomp( $line );

    if ( $line =~ /Apples/ ) {

        while ( $line =~ /Apples/ig ) {
            $counter++;
        }

        push( @lineAry, $counter );

        $initialLine++;
    }
}
close( TEXT );

# print "\n\n'Apples' occurs $counter times in file.\n";
print "Apples appear $counter times in this file\n";
print "Apples appear on these lines: ";

foreach $a ( @lineAry ) {
    print "$a, ";
}

print "\n\n";

exit;
```

Comment: $ grep -nr Apples file1 | awk '{count++;print $0}END{print count}'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code, but the reason for the line numbers being printed wrongly is that you are incrementing your variable `$counter` once each time `Apples` appears on a line and saving it to `@lineAry`. That is different from the number of the line where the string appears, and the easiest fix is to use the built-in variable `$.` which represents the number of times a read has been performed on the file handle

In addition, I would encourage you to use lexical file handles, and the three-parameter form of `open`, and check that every call to `open` has succeeded

You never use the value of `$initialLine`, and I don't understand why you have initialised it to 10

I would write it like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $filename = 'file.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename" for input: $!};

my @lines;
my $n;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    push @lines, $. if /apples/i;
    ++$n while /apples/ig;
}

print "Apples appear $n times in this file\n";
print "Apples appear on these lines: ", join( ', ', @lines ), "\n\n";
```

#### output

```
Apples appear 2 times in this file
Apples appear on these lines: 1, 4
```

Comment: `my $n = 0;` for when there is no apples.

Comment: @Kjetil: Agreed, but I would prefer to see a warning because the `on these lines` then needs fixing too, and it's just not worth it for this case.

Comment: I see your point, `if $n>0` could be appended to the last line.

Answer (score 4):

Change

`push(@lineAry, $counter);`

to

`push(@lineAry, $.);`

`$.` is a variable that stores the line number when using perl's `while (<>)`.

The alternative, if you want to use your $counter variable, is that you move the increment to increment on every line, not on every match.